# Not able to understand this @Mockbean behavior

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, springmockito

Usually I use @MockBean annotation to any JPA repository services and works fine. But I tried to use @MockBean with RestTemplate object which was getting created in the Configuration class and it didnt work.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource(value = "file:/etc/secrets/dbConfig.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class Configuration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
   @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Service Class looks something like this :

```
@Service
public class TransitCalculatorService {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    TransitDropdownInfoRepository transitDropdownInfoRepository;//MockBean works fine
}
```

In the Test Class I did something like this:

```
@Test
public class TransitCalTest2 {
    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    @MockBean
    TransitDropdownInfoRepository transitDropdownInfoRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransitCalculatorService transitCalculatorService;
    ....
}
```

I got this error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ...
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register mock
> bean org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate expected a single
> matching bean to replace but found [getRestTemplate, restTemplate]

I understood the problem. I added @Primary like this and it worked:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

What I didnt understand is the behavior. Why JPA methods transitDropdownInfoRepository  can be mocked without declaring @Primary? And why Spring got confused with a MockedBean and an actual Bean? Please someone explain in details. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Because of the name. It replaces a bean named `restTemplate` of type `RestTemplate`. Your actual `RestTemplate` bean is named `getRestTemplate`. The names don't match so it won't override/replace the bean but instead add it. Your repository is named the same and hence overridden.

Comment: Additionally due to the `@Bean` being on an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, your test also has no way of excluding that bean (it would if it would be on a regular `@Configuration` class).

Comment: Okay I think your second point is more acurate. Because I just saw a repository that is alos using getRestTemplate and using MockBean on resttemplate.

Comment: Also checked changing the MockBean this way @MockBean
    private RestTemplate getRestTemplate; got the same error again.

Comment: `@MockBean("getRestTemplate")` to explicitly set the name. Also I doubt there is a repository using the resttemplate..

Comment: `getRestTemplate` was created in the test scope
\n 1. Use `@Aurowire` to get `getResttemple` bean in test
\n  2. Exclude bean `getRestTemplate` in test

Comment: @M.Deinum No no there is no repo named resttemplate

Comment: @NgoTuoc I couldnt understand can you please share your analysis as answer? It would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: @PAMPAROY same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622107/geting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-duplicate-mock-definition-while-using-m